# Enumerating file system performance

Tags: swift, macos, performance, macos-catalina, nsfilemanager

I'm using this code to enumerate the file system and perform some very simple logic on the files.

This whole thing is being called from a DispatchQueue with a userInitiated priority - which is pretty high and yet I'm getting some very low performance for this search.

CPU spikes to around 80% for some short period and then drops to 20%-30% for the rest of the enumeration.

Disk is reading anywhere from 300KB to 700KB but it's very slow for the drive on my 16" macbook pro.

Why is the code not performing the fastest it can?

```
    let files = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: path)
    
    while let url = autoreleasepool(invoking: {files?.nextObject()}) as? String {
        let composedURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(path)/\(url)")
        
        if let matcher = try? PresetMatcher(url: composedURL, values: items, resultCallback: handler) {
            if (matcher.isValid()) {
                matcher.start()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you had the chance to measure the performance with Instruments? From my experience the FileManager is really fast but with misconfiguration and other code can be slowed down. In your case: Could it be that the PresetMatcher slows it down? Why don't you use the nextObject directly as URL (without casting to String and composing it again)?